# Copy Incoming URL Context in HTTP header in IHS server

Tags: ibmhttpserver

I am using a IHS to route the incoming url to my application by Rewrite Rule.
But i also want url to be saved so that i can use it within my application.

So my question is whether, we can copy the incoming URL to the Message HTTPHeader before performing the rewrite rule.

For eg:

### Incoming Request

```
url: 
    http://abc.test/pqr/MPP

HTTP Body:
{
 "xml": {
   "name": "testName",
   "item": { "invoice": "447632938" }
  }
}
```

### To be converted to

```
url: 
    http://xyz.test/targetApp/ss

HTTP Header:
Context:"pqr/MPP"   

HTTP Body:

{
  "xml": {
    "name": "testName",
    "item": { "invoice": "447632938" }
  }
}
```

I tried to use the below code to set the Header, but the header came as null

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(.*)/pqr/MPP" HTTP_CONTEXT=REQUEST_URI
RequestHeader set HTTP_CONTEXT %{HTTP_CONTEXT}e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below Script worked for me.

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(.*)/pgr/(.*)" HTTP_CONTEXT=$2
RequestHeader set HTTP_CONTEXT %{HTTP_CONTEXT}e
```

When i tried with the URL : http://abc.test/pqr/XYZ

I got an HTTP Header "HTTP_CONTEXT" with value

```
HTTP_CONTEXT = "XYZ"
```